# Prove that the zeta function does not converge uniformly on the half plane $\Re (z)>1$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that the zeta function $\zeta(z)=\sum\frac{1}{n^z}$ does not converge uniformly on $\Re (z)>1$.

I tried to find a counterexample: given an $\epsilon$, $\forall N$, $\exists z$ with $x=\Re(z)>1$, $\exists m,k>N$ such that

$|\zeta_m(z)-\zeta_k(z)|=|\sum_{n=k+1}^m \frac{1}{n^z}|=\sum_{n=k+1}^m \frac{1}{n^x}$

However, I could not find a suitable $\epsilon$ and $x, m,k$ because the last series looks like a p-series and therefore uniformly convergent to me. What went amiss?

Comment: I'm assuming by uniformly converging you mean the partial sums converging uniformly to the Zeta function, if so then I'm certain that you should have uniform converge on every compact subset of your region. Try an open set around $z=1$ and see if you can contradict uniform convergence on this open set.

Comment: Look at the Cauchy term from $N$ to $2N$ when say $z=1+\frac{1}{\log{2N}}$. Uniform convergence would imply convergence to zero of all such Cauchy terms regardless of $\Re z >1$, but for those above it is easy to see that the corresponding sums are greater than $\frac{1}{e\log 2}$